# Interface orientation (Landscape) on iPad weird behaviour on ios 6(xcode 4.5)

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, uikit, orientation

I am building a word game app for iPad. I want it to run only in Landscape mode.
 1. I have enabled only Landscape in plist settings.
 2. The rootview controllers view is also set Landscape.

The issue is when I run it on simulator (ios 6.1), it runs in proper Landscape mode but when I run it on iPad the views are messed up and rotated 90 degree anti clockwise. Do I need to do something else in order to have it run properly on iPad device.

Comment: I saw a post on this earlier today. It seems they have a bug with landscape orientations using storyboard.

Comment: But I am not using storyboard.

Comment: did you set the rootviewController of your window ?

Comment: @MidhunMP Yes. It is set. Everything works fine in simulator ios(6.1), It is messed up in ios 5.1

Comment: @Desparado_: I had the same issue before, I fixed it by adding the rootviewController of window in appdelegate.